# Multiple NSHTTPCookieStorage in the same app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cookies, nsurlsession

I am writing a multi-user app using `NSURLSession` and I can't figure out how to have a separate cookie storage when working with multiple `NSURLSession` instances.

I tried setting `NSURLSessionConfiguration`'s `HTTPCookieStorage` property with a `NSHTTPCookieStorage` that I alloc/init'ed myself but it doesn't work (cookies aren't stored, even if I call `setCookie:` myself)

I also tried using `[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration]` but then again, my cookies aren't stored between requests. The `Set-Cookie` header is present in the server's responses, and using `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]` works so the issue is in the code.

Is it at all possible to have separate cookie stores for different `NSURLSession` instances? I believed it was one of the main point of the new networking API.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/liaogang/5d50377c87a7e6b92e9b8a1b402c833b

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to achieve the same thing.

The ephemeralSessionConfiguration doesn't store your cookies, because its cookieAcceptPolicy is always set to NEVER, even if you try to change it to something else. Same goes for the manually allocated NSURLSessionConfiguration.

From my point of view this is in contrast to the documentation which states that ephemeral sessions use an in-memory cookie store.

I have posted a separate question regarding this issue:
[How to set cookieAcceptPolicy for ephemeral NSURLSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290234/how-to-set-cookieacceptpolicy-for-ephemeral-nsurlsession)

Comment: I ended up doing my own cookie storage by parsing the response headers using NSHTTPCookie's `cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:forURL:`...

Comment: @AlexandreBlin could you please share your code, how you have your own cookie storage